# Is repeatedly upserting the same values bad?

Tags: datomic

I'm working on an app that needs to keep track of YouTube videos. I want to periodically pull the info on the relevant videos into Datomic and then serve them as embeds with titles, descriptions, etc. A naive way to do that would be to periodically fetch all the info I want and upsert it into my db.

But most of the time, the information won't have changed. Titles and descriptions *can* change (and I want to notice when they do), but usually they won't. Using the naive approach, I'd be updating entities with the same value over and over again.

Is that bad? Will I just fill up my storage with history? Will it cause a lot of reindexing? Or should I not worry about that, and let Datomic take care of itself?

A less-naive approach would look at the current values and see if they need updating. If that's a better idea, is there an easy way to do that, or should I expect to be writing a lot of custom code for it?

Comment: how often is periodically?

Comment: @BenKamphaus It looks like `:db/cas` lets you only assert if the current value is some given value, but doesn't let you make the assertion only if the current value *isn't* some given value. That said, if there isn't an appropriate built-in transaction function, writing my own transaction function is probably a good way to do this.

Comment: I've revised my comment to point you here: http://blog.datomic.com/2012/08/atomic-chocolate.html

Comment: Ah, thanks! In that case, I won't use a transaction function after all. :) It sounds like the right thing to do is to extract what's new from the state of the world YouTube is giving me as close to the YouTube-side of my app as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upserting too often is definitely an issue for performance of the database. Yes, it will cause indexing issue, but also in terms of speed, its not an ideal solution.

If your app's performance has time as an important factor, I'd write custom code to check and then update if necessary

Comment: Is the performance issue just that an upsert will be slower than skipping the upsert where it's unnecessary, or will performing lots of unnecessary upserts cause other queries and transactions to slow down because of unnecessary data in the system?

Comment: In other words, can I naively upsert every time for now and later add a check to make it more performant, or will the data from my old naive upserts continue to bog down Datomic even after I add the check?

Comment: You're not doing it at a scale big enough to matter. As in, the extra data churn isn't holding up the indexer. And you're clearly not heavily invested in querying history for these entities. So all that's really lost is that some of your transactions for your youtube entities don't actually represent changes -- not a big deal. It's minor data model slippage. I have yet to write my own abstraction for "only transact the keys that have changed or else do nothing", but I need to soon and considering using this: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.data/diff

Comment: The only performance hit on the database I see is that every transaction produces a transaction datom even if the transaction is empty. If you upsert only one entity per transaction, you will produce many empty transactions with unneeded transaction datoms. But if you upset say 1.000 entities per transaction and its unlikely that every one is unchanged, you don't waste anything.